# Instant Article Builder - How do I add width and height in AdRules?

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

I need to add fixed values in the ad rule. It's possible? or other way?

I'm trying this way, but the width and height don't work. I also tried using 'constant' and 'value' for the width and height, worked only for the url

```
    {
    "generator_name": "facebook-instant-articles-builder",
    "generator_version": "0.2.0",
    "rules": [
        {
            "class": "TextNodeRule"
        },
        {
            "class": "GlobalRule",
            "selector": "html",
            "properties": {
                "article.title": {
                    "attribute": "content",
                    "selector": "span i",
                    "type": "element"
                },
                "article.publish": {
                    "format": "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s",
                    "selector": "[ia-date]",
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "author.name": {
                    "selector": "[ia-author]",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "image.url": {
                    "attribute": "content",
                    "selector": "[property=\"og:image\"]",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "article.body": {
                    "selector": ".text",
                    "type": "element"
                },
                "article.canonical": {
                    "attribute": "href",
                    "selector": "link[rel=canonical]",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "EmphasizedRule",
            "selector": "em"
        },
        {
            "class": "BoldRule",
            "selector": "b, strong"
        },
        {
            "class": "ImageRule",
            "selector": "img",
            "properties": {
                "image.url": {
                    "attribute": "src",
                    "selector": "img",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "image.caption": {
                    "attribute": "src",
                    "selector": "img",
                    "type": "element"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "AdRule",
            "selector": "[ia-ad-url]",
            "properties": {
                "ad.url": {
                    "attribute": "ia-ad-url",
                    "selector": "[ia-ad-url]",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "ad.width": {
                    "attribute": "ia-ad-width",
                    "selector": "[ia-ad-width]",
                    "type": "int"
                },
                "ad.height": {
                    "attribute": "ia-ad-height",
                    "selector": "[ia-ad-height]",
                    "type": "int"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "PassThroughRule",
            "selector": ".summary-content,.summary-news,.slot-g,.text,.youtube-embed,.related-content-hyperlink"
        }
    ]
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/sdk/transformer/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/builder